# How to automatically run VSCode’s own built in command

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, automation, ide

I'm trying to configure VSCode to run some commands on load and generally that works.

What I can't find in the documentation is how to run VSCode’s own commands, e.g. I'd like to run `Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal (In Active Workspace)`.

How can I run any of VSCode various own’s commands with a `.vscode/tasks.json` config?

Comment: If you mean built-in "commands" instead of "tasks" you should edit your question.  They are very different things.

Comment: @Mark thanks, updated question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - (after I fixed it):

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",

  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "run new terminal command",
      "command": "${workbench.action.terminal.newInActiveWorkspace}",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

in your `tasks.json`.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_command-variables for more on using commands in tasks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to open any new terminals for me. Also note I am specifically looking to open the "In Active Workspace" to load the venv.